# How to create symlink maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have an question for you.

I have to create symbolic links using antrun to some .properties files in folder '/opt/apache-servicemix/etc' like this:

Ex: ln -s /etc/opt/ESG/file.properties file.properties.cfg

```
[lsav@asimov etc]$ pwd
/opt/apache-servicemix/etc
[lsav@asimov etc]$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lsav calapp    51 Mar 13 13:51 esb-
actorspecificvalidation.properties.cfg -> /etc/opt/ESG/esb-
actorspecificvalidation.properties
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lsav calapp    43 Mar 13 13:51 esb-
anysystemrouter.properties.cfg -> /etc/opt/ESG/esb-
anysystemrouter.properties
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lsav calapp    33 Mar 13 13:51 esb-batch.properties.cfg -> 
/etc/opt/ESG/esb-batch.properties
```

This is what I have:

```
<apply executable="ln" dir="/opt/apache-servicemix/etc">
     <arg value="-sf"/>
     <srcfile/>
     <fileset dir="/etc/opt/ESG">
         <include name="*.properties"/>
    </fileset>
    <mergemapper to="*.properties.cfg"/>
</apply>
```

This works BUT creates symlink with name identical with filename. I want to be:
file.properties.cfg

How can I add .cfg extension to symlink? I tried to use mergemapper but doesn't work ( I don't know if mergemapper is what I need in this case)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this within a build?

Comment: yes. I want to make a deployment using maven. And do some actions like: copy files, create symlinks etc

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right path to go...I would suggest either to use a separate script which can be triggered via a CI solution like Jenkins....

Comment: I use Jenkins to trigger this build. But I don't want to make shell script to execute this action. I want to make Jenkins job as dumb as possible ( if possible only git clone repo and invoke maven goals)... and all the actions added in pom.xml

Comment: So, you suggest to create a shell script for that and lauched with antrun plugin? Is this possible?

Comment: I won't launch that via Maven at all cause Maven is not a deployment tool...